# How to use ejs in react js

Tags: reactjs, ejs

How would I use ejs with react js? The code below is used to display the front end and the code I want to use in my react app. And a js file is used for the backend that send the data to a MySQL database. I have tried many ways but it didn't work I even tried the online converter but they didn't work either. Can anyone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Currency Converter in Javascript</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container col-sm-12" id="mainform">
        <div id="signupbox" style=" margin-top:50px" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">                                    
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">Register</div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" >
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
                            <div class="alert alert-success col-sm-12"><%= message %></div>
                        <% } %>
                        <div id="signupalert" style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger">
                            <p>Error:</p>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="first_name" class="col-md-3 control-label">First Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="last_name" class="col-md-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="mob_no" class="col-md-3 control-label">Mobile Number</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="mob_no" placeholder="Mobile Number">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="mob_no" class="col-md-3 control-label">Profile Image</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="uploaded_image" accept=""/>
                            </div>
                        </div>                                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="user_name" class="col-md-3 control-label">User Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" placeholder="User Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <!-- Button -->                                      
                            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                <button id="btn-signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i> &nbsp Register</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </form>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you do this instead of using a rest API?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use EJS instead of just using JSX? I feel like this would make your life easier.

Comment: Why would you want to use EJS *with* React?